# Looking for default yAxis options for Highmaps to be able to add it from code

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to remove and then add an yAxis for the highmaps using javascript.

However, I cannot find axis's settings that are responsible for fixing issues with zooming and dragging after zoom. 
Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/bso80657/

If you comment lines 53 and 54, you will see a normal default behaviour: zoom is  working fine.

Issues with my code after removing and adding yAxis:

1. It is not possible to use a mouse wheel to zoom in.
2. If you use 'plus' button to zoom in and then drag the map a bit up or down - it resets zoom settings.

I could figure out that the axis should be reversed and hidden.

Here is a piece of code responsible for removing and adding an axis.

```
var axis = {
      reversed: true,                
      visible: false,
};

//Comment the next two lines to be able to check the default behaviour
chart.yAxis[0].remove(false);
chart.addAxis(axis, false);
```

What other options I should use to fix this zoom issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Starina, May I ask why do you need to remove and add `yAxis` in Highmaps?

Comment: I need to show different types of charts with lots of different settings at one page. So, I clear the chart and add as many axis I need for the next one. Then I show the graph. I hoped I could do the same when I use 'map' type.

Comment: The zoom functionality in Highmaps is related with the basic axes. Maybe you can work on an additional axes?